# Joining 2 select queries irrespective of no. of records

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables

```
table 1                               table 2
------------------                   ----------------------
description   paidamt                description recievedamt
ele. bill     200                    donation    1000
stationary    500                    fees        200
salary        1000
```

and I want result in following format (data will be sorted on basis of date)

```
description  debit credit
---------------------------
ele. bill    200
donation            1000
stationary   500
fees                200
salary       1000
```

matter is, when I set amt to debit then I can not set credit column as blank or when I set amt to credit of perticular column then I can not set debit column as blank. I was working on following query....

```
WHEN Payment_Voucher_Master.grand_tot <> '0' 
  THEN '' 
  ELSE 'dgf'
END credit 
FROM Receipt_Voucher_Master,Payment_Voucher_Master
GROUP BY Payment_Voucher_Master.PaidTo,Payment_Voucher_Master.grand_tot

SELECT Receipt_Voucher_Master.PaidTo 
    AS description, Receipt_Voucher_Master.grand_total as credit,
CASE 
WHEN Receipt_Voucher_Master.grand_total <> '0'
  THEN '' 
  ELSE 'dgf'
END debit 
FROM Receipt_Voucher_Master,Payment_Voucher_Master
GROUP BY Receipt_Voucher_Master.PaidTo,Receipt_Voucher_Master.grand_total;
```

I was trying to join these 2 queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @table1 table (
[description] varchar(20),
paidamt money
)

declare @table2 table (
[description] varchar(20),
recievedamt money
)

insert @table1 values 
('ele. bill',200),
('stationary',500),
('salary',1000)

insert @table2 values 
('donation',1000),
('fees',200)

select [description],paidamt as [debit],null as [credit]  from @table1
union all
select [description],null as [debit],recievedamt as [credit] from @table2
```

Comment: giving the result as per required...let me work on it.. will get back to u soon.. thanks for qik reply

Comment: i have used ur query and working fine with small changes and sorting on d basis of dates... thaks alot !!!!

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you,

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(a.[description],b.[description]) AS [description],
    ISNULL(a.[paidamt],'') AS debit, 
    ISNULL(b.[recievedamt],'') AS credit
FROM [table1] AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN [table2] AS b
    ON a.[description] = b.[description]
```

Comment: giving the result as per required...let me work on it.. will get back to u soon.. thanks for qik reply